# How to display a specific type of content from a database with Vue

Tags: vue.js

I want to display only a specific type of blog content from Firebase. 
In the database, each blog has a title, type and content. Some blogs have the same type, for example, some can be about dogs and some can be about cats.

I'm able to display the blog content from firebase but I want to display blogs of type dogs only.

My problem with the code below is that if I use `blogs_with_correct_genera` in the `v-for` I create two blog templates but with empty content because it does not have and `id` attribute. Two blog templates are created because `blogs_with_correct_genera` only has two items of type dog.

If I change it to "blogs" which is linked to the database I get the content of the blogs but it also creates 3 blog templates instead of 2, because `blogs` has 2 blogs of type dog and 1 blog of type cat.

Below is the html calling the method `getBlogOfType(param1,param2)`

```
      <b-card v-for="blog in blogs_with_correct_genera" title="Title" img-src="https://placekitten.com/500/350" img-alt="Image" img-top>
        <b-card-text>
          {{getBlogOfType("dog",blog.id)}}
        </b-card-text>
        <b-card-text class="small text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</b-card-text>
      </b-card>
```

Below is the method `getBlogOfType(param1,param2)`

```
    getBlogOfType (blog_type, doc_id) {
      var blogs_with_correct_type = []
      var blogs_doc_id = []

      for (var i=0; i <= this.blogs.length-1; i++){
        if (this.blogs[i].type == blog_type){
          blogs_with_correct_type.push(this.blogs[i].content);
          blogs_doc_id.push(this.blogs[i].id)
        }
      }
      this.blogs_with_correct_genera = blogs_with_correct_type
      //console.log(this.blogs_with_correct_genera)
      var location = blogs_doc_id.indexOf(doc_id)
      console.log(this.blogs[location])

      return this.blogs_with_correct_genera[location]
    }
```

How can I modify the code such that I only display blogs of a specific type so that only dog posts are displayed if I call the method `getBlogOfType("dog")`

Comment: Can you post some of the data? Possibly some example code (with hard coded data)? You should just have to query for that property...

Answer (score 0):

If we could look at the data it might make a bit more sense. For filtering you can combine a [v-for and a v-if](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-v-if) if the condition you're requiring is trivial enough.